# Copy/Cut collapsed code and have it collapsed when pasted

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I copy or cut collapsed code and paste it somewhere else, the code gets expanded. Is there any way to make Visual Studio to retain the collapse/expand 
state when copy/cut/pasted?

I'm hoping that I can rearrange methods order quickly by cutting and pasting while all the implementaion details are nicely collapsed.

I'm working on VS2008 (C#) right now, but any tip on VS2010 is also appreciated.

Comment: You could always do ctrl-M-M that should collapse the code. Not exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: After ctrl-M-M, please try cut an entire method (which is now collapsed to a single line) and paste it somewhere. The single line gets expanded. I'm wondering if I can get it remain collapsed after paste.

Comment: I have the same issue.  It is such a hassle when moving around large chunks of code.  I've created an issue on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672501/visual-studio-cut-paste-collapse-text-expands-all-everything) and up-voted a similar feature addition in [ReSharper](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-95932?projectKey=RSRP&query=%23{File+structure+}).

Comment: Me too (VS 2012)!!! Any news about this issue? :(

Comment: still the same in VS2015 and VS2017 and it's annoying. Seems there is no or will ever be an update on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of doing what you are asking, but if you currently use [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) (or are interested in trialing or buying it) then it includes a [File Structure](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#File_Structure) window in which you can easily change the order of class members, classes themselves and regions simply by dragging them around.

In addition it adds [keyboard shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Code_Reordering) for moving whole methods up and down within a type.

Beyond these simple rearrangement functions, it also has a wealth of [refactorings](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html) for moving methods within the type hierachy, extracting interfaces, &c.

Comment: The File Structure window has nuances as well.

Comment: @jberger And by "nuances" you mean "things that expand when they should stay collapsed". :) But at least they are regions/groups rather than individual methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about Creating a macro for pasting+collapsing ?

Comment: I have not written any Macro myself yet. This may be a good exercise for me :)

Comment: The trick is to have every node keep the exact same state (collapsed or expanded) after the paste.  (Not just a Paste, Collapse All macro.)

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same disturbing behavior. I collapse manually methods, since it is more readable and accessible when you have thousands of lines in one class. After pasting an import line , all the code is expanded. And it is an overkill to collapse them again. It is very interesting that it only happens when I work with JS code. For example, When working with PYTHON, this problematic behavior does not seem to happen any more.

> CMD + K + 2

is my makeshift to this problem , since I usually collapse only methods which are under class making them level 2.

But you loose your custom collapse structure and I think **this is a bug** since this behavior does not happen in *Python* code but happens in *JS* Code.

(Note:Don't tested in other languages yet.)